# Ember.js: Template type not defined?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, url-routing

The user is being correctly routed by the main router to the App.IndexRoute below:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function() {
    return App.Contact.find();
  },
  init: function() {console.log('were in the indexroute! ive been created.')},
  controller: 'index',

  setupController: function(controller) {
        controller.set('content', App.Contact.find());
        console.log('the IndexController is set up, with the model equal to ' + controller.get('content') + '.');
    },


  renderTemplate: function() {
    this._super();
      this.render('contacts', {
        outlet: 'sidebar',
        into:'index',
        controller: 'contacts'
      });
      this.render('map', {
        into: 'index',
        outlet: 'map', //cannot connect outlet yet, acc. GitHub ember-data gist #1838
        controller: 'map'
      });
    }
});
```

But the index page refuses to load any of the dynamic, Handlebars-defined content. Removing `this._super()` from the `renderTemplate` function yields a Type Error, with 'connectOutlet' not defined. I'm getting the comments in the Handlebars templates on the index page (hidden, of course), so I know they're loading correctly.

Can anyone spot any issues with the route definition? If not, I'll have to delve further. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Notes: Ember, ruby, rails and so on all up-to-date as of writing. Chrome console debugger gives:

```
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.1 ember.js:348
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.3 ember.js:348
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.9.1
```

Comment: renderTemplate by default just calls this.render(), which in this case is what's setting up the default index template into which the other renders are trying to insert other templates. That's why removing super causes the error. You can replace the super call with this.render() if it makes the code clearer for you. Can you show your templates, as well? Are there custom views associated with the templates?

Comment: This could be because you aren't calling `this._super()` from inside the `init` method. Try adding it, or deleting the `init` override altogether.

Comment: Actually, `Route` doesn't have an `init`, and it inherits directly from `Ember.Object`, which is just `CoreObject`, which has an empty `init`. so this is one of the few cases where you don't have to call `_super()` in `init`. But, yeah, it's not a good idea to get into the habit of not calling `this._super()` when you override `init`.